Custom Validation-Make any one Field required at item level in Rendering Parameters template
Created custom item validation rule and in standard values of parameter template as suggested in below mentioned link.
Make one of two sitecore content fields required?
Here requirement is to validate the item fields in rendering params template. However for some reason item created using params template is not showing any error message in case of any one of empty fields.
Also, If i check standard values of template, it is showing validation.
Is there anyone who faced this same issue?

I'm fairly sure that validation does not work on Rendering Parameters

Try to apply the validation rule on the field itself instead of the standard value

@GauravAgarwal- Requirement is to check one of  fields must be fulfilled , so need to apply item rule in rendering parameters template itself
